# Evaluating $\int_0^x \lvert \cos t \rvert dt$

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, definite-integrals

in my mathbook there is given a solution to 
$$\int_0^x \lvert \cos t \rvert \, dt $$
but without any hints or tips.

$$\int_0^x \lvert \cos t \rvert \, dt =    \sin\left(x - \pi \left\lfloor \frac x \pi + \frac 1 2\right\rfloor \right)    + 2\left\lfloor \frac x \pi + \frac 1 2\right\rfloor$$

Its really hard  to guess what they did.

Can u give me any kind of hints?

Comment: Integrate separately where $\cos t$ is positive and where it is negative.  Observe the periodic behavior.  Then try to get a formula that fits it.

Comment: @Ant One can solve equations. "Solve an integral" is something students say, but that does not make it correct.

Comment: @900sit-upsaday Just beat me to it!

Comment: @900sit-upsaday thank you! I'm not a native speaker so I appreciate these corrections ;-)

Comment: I am sorry but i still dont get it.

Comment: @Max94 $|\cos(t)| \equiv \begin{cases} \cos(t) \quad \mbox{if} \quad t \geq 0 \\ -\cos(t) \quad \mbox{if} \quad t<0\end{cases}$